# How to check if width doesn´t have a fixed value

Tags: cypress

How to check that element that doesn´t have a fixed width doesn´t have a fixed width

if i do ex. `cy.get('element').should('have.css', 'width', 'auto)` it will fail as it will check that actual set width of the element.

Comment: can you add the html code?

Comment: hmm, this is just an example but it´s exactly the same. <div class="abc">this is a test<div>. Class abc doesn´t have a width set but will have a width of ex. 20 px because of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Since 'have.css' uses `JQuery`'s `css(...)` function under the hood (which computes the exact width), you'll have to use `window.getComputedStyle`

```js
const haveStyle = (name, value) => ($el) => {
  expect($el[0].ownerDocument.defaultView.getComputedStyle($el[0])[name]).eq(value)
}

cy.get('.el').should(haveStyle('width', 'auto'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use `have.attr` followed by a `contain`:

```js
cy.get('element')
  .should('have.attr', 'style')
  .should('contain', 'width: auto;');
```

Comment: Does this work when the element has a class and gains it's CSS from a style-sheet, Philippe?

Comment: I would expect result only if the style is inline, no?

Comment: Oh, I think you are right. This doesn't seem to work if e.g. the `width` is set via CSS class and only works if the attribute `style` is set . Thanks for the hint!